# Get a service inside a model

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I'm pretty new to zend 2 and want to implement a couple of models which can be accessed from **wherever** I want, i.e. from controllers and from other models.

From controllers it already works. But I don't know how to do in inside a model which has no `getServiceLocator()` method. Besides I can't access service Locator from inside the model to get the config.

```
namespace Bsz\Services;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareInterface;

class OpenUrl implements ServiceLocatorAwareInterface {

    protected $serviceLocator;

    public function __construct() {
        $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
        $config = $sm->get('config');
        var_dump($sm); //null
    }    
    public function setServiceLocator(\Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $this->serviceLocator = $serviceLocator;
    }
    public function getServiceLocator()
    {
        return $this->serviceLocator;
    }
}
```

Snippet from `module.config.php`

```
'service_manager' => [
    'invokables' => [
        'bsz\openurl' => 'Bsz\Services\OpenUrl',
    ]
],
```

And here my Action, which already works

```
public function indexAction() {

   $OpenUrl = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('bsz\openurl');
   //works, is an object of type bsz\openurl. 
}
```

So my questions is: how to properly get a service manager inside a model which is itself used as service? How to do this in other models?

I've found many questions like this and tried around a lot but still did not get this working. Maybe version differences in Zend? **We use Zend 2.3.7**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `OpenUrl` service *depends* on it's configuration. The configuration is therefore a *dependency* of the service. There is no point creating the service without it's configuration.

You have registered the `bsz\openurl` service as an 'invokable' class. This means that when you request the service, the service manager will instantiate the the `Bsz\Services\OpenUrl` class without any constructor arguments being passed in. This isn't what you want, you *need* the configuration as soon as the class is created.

**Register the service with a service factory**

> [The factory [method] pattern is a creational pattern which uses factory methods to deal with the problem of creating objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).

To implement this ZF2 ships with it's own factory interface, `Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface`, which the our new factory should implement.

```
namespace Bsz\Services;

use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

class OpenUrlFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $config  = $this->getConfig($serviceLocator);
        $service = new OpenUrl($config);

        return $service;
    }

    protected function getConfig(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $config = $serviceLocator->get('config');

        if (! isset($config['open_url'])) {
            throw new \RuntimeException('The service configuration key \'open_url\' could not be found');
        }
        return $config['open_url'];
    }
}
```

Now we can update the `module.config.php` and change the service type to a factory.

```
'service_manager' => [
    'factories' => [
        'bsz\openurl' => 'Bsz\Services\OpenUrlFactory',
    ],
],
```

After this if `SomeService` *depends* on `OpenUrl` then you can repeat the factory process with a new `SomeServiceFactory` where the dependency is `OpenUrl`.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer for the first question right now: erviceManager`has to be injected into the model. This can only be done with a factory:

`Factory.php`

```
namespace Bsz\Services;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager;

class Factory {

    public static function getOpenUrl(ServiceManager $sm)
    {        
        return new \Bsz\Services\OpenUrl($sm);
    }
}
```

`module.config.php`

```
 'service_manager' => [
    'factories' => [
        'bsz\openurl' => 'Bsz\Services\Factory::getOpenUrl',            
    ]
],
```

But how to retrieve this Service from another model which has no `getServiceLocator` method?

Comment: Injecting the ServiceManager into the class is regarded as bad practice; it makes testing difficult and unnecessarily couples the implementation to ZF2. Use the factory to load the config first and then pass that to the `OpenUrl` class as in my example.

Comment: Why do I need the `setServiceLocator` method then?

Comment: You don't! The examples I guess you have been reading would take advantage of a [ZF2  'initializer' which would inject the service locator into any class implementing the  `ServiceLocatorAwareInterface`](https://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.mvc.services.html#servicemanager). If you have a factory giving your service all it needs, there is no need for the service locator to be within the service, hence no need for any `setServiceLocator` etc.

Comment: ok. And how do I retrieve the Model in Another model? This seems to be really complicated...

Comment: Inject model2 into constructor of model1

Comment: Hm. I'm working with a large OpenSource project. I need to adapt it to our needs. Injecting would mean to change many lines, factories, constructors etc. It would probably be better if I keep creating a new instance? That can be done in one or to lines at the position where I need the model.